# React / Material UI Checkboxes looses check visual on tab switch

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have been pulling my hair out for ages on this one - Checkboxes (50) are rendered within a tab, and after checking and switching tabs and going back again the value is stored but the checkbox looses the visual.

```
<Tabs value={selectedTab} onChange={handleTabChange} variant="scrollable" scrollButtons="auto" aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example">
          <Tab label="NOTES"/>
          <Tab label="GEAR"/>
</Tabs>

{selectedTab === 0 && (
  <>
    {listItem.map((checkbox, index) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel key={index + checkbox.Name} className="twocolelement"
        control={
          <Checkbox
            name={checkbox.Name}
            value={checkbox.Weight}
            id={checkbox.Category}
            checked={isChecked[index]}
            color="primary"
            onChange={event => handleCheckboxChange(index, event)}
            onClick={(e) => isCheckboxChecked(index, e.target.checked)}
          />
        }
        label={(checkbox.Brand) + ' ' + (checkbox.Name)}
      />

          );
        })}
  </>
)}
    {selectedTab === 1 && (
  <>
    <Checkbox></Checkbox>
  </>
)}
```

```
const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

// Function called anytime the tab changes
function handleTabChange(event, value) {
  setSelectedTab(value);
}
```

Any reason why this would be happening? Been trying for awhile to sort it out.

Comment: please explain "but the checkbox looses the visual", the explanation is not clear, I suggest you improve it.

Comment: What's checkbox (50) ? You loose visual, you mean you lose the state of the checkbox ? What's the implementation of checkbox ? You need to provide more information if you want good answers. From what I guess you lose "visuals" (state ?) because when selectedTab change Checkbox is not rendered anymore so the state goes back to initial state.

Comment: Sorry I mean visual in terms of the checkbox does not show as checked. 50 is just the number of checkboxes I have in that tab. Is it because of selectedTab? How do I keep the checkboxes state between switching tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting display: none in the style when the checkbox is not selected instead of removing it from the dom.

example:

```
    <div>
        <Tabs
          value={selectedTab}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="basic tabs example"
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" />
          <Tab label="Item Two" />
          <Tab label="Item Three" />
        </Tabs>
        {[0, 1, 2].map((el) => (
          <Checkbox
            style={{ display: selectedTab === el ? '' : 'none' }}
          />
        ))}
   </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mui-2bd5dq?file=index.js